# Web Scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to scraping and I'm stuck on scraping a webpage which contains some quotes I want to extract.

Could you please also check the code for copying the scraped data to CSV file?

[image: here]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = "http://www.values.com/inspirational-quotes"
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

quotes=[] # a list to store quotes

table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'container'})

for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'quote'}):
    quote = {}
    quote['theme'] = row.h5.text
    quote['url'] = row.a['href']
    quote['img'] = row.img['src']
    quote['lines'] = row.h6.text
    quote['author'] = row.p.text
    quotes.append(quote)

filename = 'inspirational_quotes.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['theme','url','img','lines','author'])
    w.writeheader()
    for quote in quotes:
        w.writerow(quote)
```

I'm getting error at the `"findAll"` function.

```
for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'quote'}):    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll
```

Comment: Your error means that `soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'container'})` returned `None`, i.e. a `div` element with the `container` id was not found. Have you checked the HTML? You can show the relevant part you want to extract in your question. I think the problem is that the URL you are using actually redirects to a different page: https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes

Comment: @dspencer Yes sir, i have checked the HTML, "Container" seems to be correct, checked with "row" too.
Could you once check the page, and yes it does redirects to a different age once we click on a quote.

Comment: @dspencer 
table = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'all_quotes'})
This was the change in code, which did the work.

Comment: I got the "csv" file with header as 'theme','url','img','lines','author'
but the data pertaining to ones against them is blank.
What i might be doing wrong ?

Comment: hi there - irunned this and i got back the following result: 

´https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=1
https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=n..
https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=44´

and besides that ´

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_values_com.py", line 31, in <module>
    with open('inspirational_quotes.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
[Finished in 55.861s]
´
i am just musing how - i am trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html of that site are different from the ones you have defined within your script. I've rectified the first three fields. I suppose you can do the rest. The following should work for you.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page={}"

quotes = []
page = 1

while True:
    r = requests.get(URL.format(page))
    print(r.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

    if not soup.select_one("#all_quotes .text-center > a"):break
    for row in soup.select("#all_quotes .text-center"):
        quote = {}
        try:
            quote['quote'] = row.select_one('a img.shadow').get("alt")
        except AttributeError: quote['quote'] = ""
        try:
            quote['url'] = row.select_one('a').get('href')
        except AttributeError: quote['url'] = ""
        try:
            quote['img'] = row.select_one('a img.shadow').get('src')
        except AttributeError: quote['img'] = ""
        quotes.append(quote)

    page+=1

with open('inspirational_quotes.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['quote','url','img'])
    w.writeheader()
    for quote in quotes:
        w.writerow(quote)
```

Comment: hi there - irunned this and i got back the following result: 

´https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=1
https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=2..
https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=n..
https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=44´

and besides that ´

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_values_com.py", line 31, in <module>
    with open('inspirational_quotes.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
[Finished in 55.861s]
´

Comment: @zero I got the perfect answer.
You sure didn't create any excel file with that name already ? Because it creates one the pages are scraped.

Answer (score 0):

The site doesnt have any div tags with the attribute id: container. You could use the [Quote API](https://pprathameshmore.github.io/QuoteGarden/)

```
from requests import get
url='https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/quotes/random'
res=get(url)
res=res.json()
quote=res["quoteText"]
quoteauthor=res["quoteAuthor"]
```

Comment: Sir, i couldn't understand the answer which you gave.
the above asked question was executable like 1 Year back.
Could you please check it once again.